# Monitoring module missing in Icingaweb2

Tags: linux-mint, monitoring, icinga2

I installed **icingaweb2** but in the setup wizard I had not the posibility of installing the monitoring module. I search in /etc/icingaweb2/modules and there is no monitoring module, the only module int the folder is the translate module.

I finished the installation and in the modules menu option it is not listed [image]

I tried reinstalling icingaweb2 but the monitoring module it does not appear

I am using Linux Mint 18 sarah distro

Answer (score 4):

You might be missing the package for the monitoring module. Perhaps cingaweb2-module-monitoring from https://packages.debian.org/sid/admin/icingaweb2-module-monitoring may work?

I had the same issue as you on my raspbian (debian on raspberry pi) and installing that package helped.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it was helpfull just i did it with Mint. Yo directed me to fix the problem. Kind regards!

Answer (score 1):

The final solution, the package icingaweb2-monitoring was missing.

To install it in Linux Mintt via Synaptic.

Menu > Administration > **Synaptic Package Manager**

Use quick filter and search for icingaweb2. I did not have monitoring installed:

[image]

Just mark it and apply.

Then in the webapp goto Configuration > Modules  and enable monitoring